# Replacing machinekey values using web.config transforms

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, one-click-web-publishing

In my web.config file I have the following entry:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <machineKey validationKey="656....9CCF" decryptionKey="9020.....659" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I need to swap the `validationKey` and `decryptionKey` values under certain web publish profiles using the web config transform method.  I'm struggling however, as I can't find any examples that achieve more than a basic connection string swap, or suchlike.

Is it possible to actually modify this part of the file using config transforms?

My attempt so far doesn't get recognised when I preview the transform...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <system.web>
        <machineKey validationKey="AE3E7...FAB49" decryptionKey="ADS32....32423twe" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(validationKey)" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
<machineKey validationKey="AE3E7...FAB49" decryptionKey="ADS32....32423twe" 
         xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="XPath(../machineKey)"/>
```

Note that I replaced the `xdt:Transform` to "SetAttributes" not "Replace".

For more reference you can check [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can also test the transform [here](https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/).

Comment: Works beautifully.  Thank you!